# Simple docker command does not work: x509: cannot validate certificate

Tags: docker

Hi I just install docker i open the cmd and create a default docker machine:

```
C:\git>docker-machine create --driver virtualbox default
Running pre-create checks...
Creating machine...
(default) Copying C:\Users\NGT1IMB\.docker\machine\cache\boot2docker.iso to C:\Users\NGT1IMB\.docker\machine\machines\default\boot2docker.iso...
(default) Creating VirtualBox VM...
(default) Creating SSH key...
(default) Starting the VM...
(default) Check network to re-create if needed...
(default) Waiting for an IP...
Waiting for machine to be running, this may take a few minutes...
Detecting operating system of created instance...
Waiting for SSH to be available...
Detecting the provisioner...
Provisioning with boot2docker...
Copying certs to the local machine directory...
Copying certs to the remote machine...
Setting Docker configuration on the remote daemon...
Checking connection to Docker...
Docker is up and running!
To see how to connect your Docker Client to the Docker Engine running on this virtual machine, run: docker-machine env default

C:\git>docker-machine ls
NAME      ACTIVE   DRIVER       STATE     URL                         SWARM   DOCKER    ERRORS
default   *        virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.100:2376           v1.11.2

C:\git>docker-machine env default
SET DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
SET DOCKER_HOST=tcp://192.168.99.100:2376
SET DOCKER_CERT_PATH=C:\Users\NGT1IMB\.docker\machine\machines\default
SET DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME=default
REM Run this command to configure your shell:
REM     @FOR /f "tokens=*" %i IN ('docker-machine env default') DO @%i
```

And then i got this error when trying to follow the tutorial:

```
C:\git>docker run hello-world
docker: An error occurred trying to connect: Post https://192.168.99.100:2376/v1.23/containers/create: x509: cannot vali
date certificate for 192.168.99.100 because it doesn't contain any IP SANs.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

Any reply is much appreciated.

Comment: what tutorial are you following? Looks outdated to me, I'd recommend you to use docker toolbox https://www.docker.com/products/docker-toolbox

Comment: I installed toolbox and follow this guide: https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/windows/

Comment: try the very first option `Using the Docker Quickstart Terminal`, it will do all the steps for you

Comment: I tried that also. It automatically creates the default VM, but running docker run returns the same error.

Comment: here is something similar you can try
https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/3099

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is i am behind the company NLTM proxy. So when creating the default VM,
I must set the proxy:

```
docker-machine create -d virtualbox --engine-env HTTP_PROXY=http://<host>.<port> -engine-env HTTPS_PROXY=https://<host>.<port> default
```

Moreover, I am using CNTLM to setup a local proxy via localhost:3128.
And the default VM runs on Virtualbox with NAT setup. So I need to set

`HTTP_PROXY=http://192.168.99.1:3128`

For the explaination, please visit [here](https://forums.docker.com/t/beginner-having-trouble-with-docker-behind-company-proxy/3968/6)

Thanks for your suggestion, vitr